# Iterating through object array with type enum

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following structure:

```js
export interface Membership {
  id: string;
  permissions: Permissions;
}

export type Permissions = {
  [key in PermissionsEnum]?: boolean;
}

export enum PermissionsEnum {
  projectAdmin,
  projectEdit,
  projectView
}
```

I now have an object array of membership `memberships: Membership[];`

How can I check, if the memberships holds a membership object with id 'xyz' and permission 'projectAdmin' = true?

The following does not work:

```js
    return !!this.memberships?.find((membership) =>
      membership.id === 'xyz' && membership.permissions.hasOwnProperty(PermissionsEnum.projectAdmin) && membership.permissions[PermissionsEnum.projectAdmin] === true);
```

The problem is, that accessing the permissions enum would always return undefined, eventhough the console.log of the permission object looks like this:

`Object { projectAdmin: true, projectEdit: true, projectView: true }`

Edit:

sample of memberships object holding a single membership:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "permissions": {
      "projectAdmin": true,
      "projectEdit": true,
      "projectView": true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Seems like what you really want is a string enum: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums. `PermissionsEnum.projectAdmin` returns a number.

Comment: when you use key in Enum, it represent the values (0,1,2), you want to use key in keyof typeof Enum to get the properties names, but even then your code wouldn't work because you are accessing it like this permissions[Enum] which essentially means permissions[0] which is undefined.

Comment: You are right, that's exactly what happens, even when accessing permissions[0] it will return undefined. Can I access the enum with 0, 1, 2 represenation at all?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `permissions` is an array, so you would need to iterate through it somehow to check for the desired object.

```
let membership = !!this.memberships.find((membership) => membership.id === 'xyz')

return membership.permissions.find((permission) => permission[PermissionsEnum.projectAdmin] === true)
```

**In Response to question edit**

It might simplify this for you quite a lot if you make this just a string or array of strings stored under permissions? You can still type this using union.

```
export interface Membership {
  id: string;
  permissions: Permissions;
}

export type Permissions = 'Admin' | 'Edit' | 'View'
```

Then you only need check if the string exists.

```
return this.memberships.find((membership) => membership.id === 'xyz' && membership.permission === 'Admin')
```

**If you want to use enum approach**

```
export enum PermissionsEnum {
  projectAdmin = 'projectAdmin',
  projectEdit = 'projectEdit',
  projectView = 'projectView'
}

return this.memberships.find((membership) => membersbip.id === 'xyz' && membership.permissions[PermissionsEnum.projectAdmin] === true)
```

Comment: I think that was incorrect on my side, the Permissions is not an array - I edited my original post

Comment: @Tea2k I have modified my answer, is there a reason you are using an enum here? If so maybe the above may not be helpful but let me know :)

Comment: Thanks! Yea because it's a boolean with true/false:(

Comment: Okay, well I added another line for the enum approach hope it helps!

Comment: what if enum like this? export enum PermissionsEnum {
  projectAdmin = "projectAdmin",
  projectEdit = "projectAdmin",
  projectView = "projectAdmin"
}  then also the aswer is available.

Comment: Yeah good spot, your enum values are currently `0,1,2` you would need to change them to @SarathMohandas suggestion.

Comment: Looks good! But with using a string enum, membership.permissions[PermissionsEnum.projectAdmin] === true does not work (Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Permissions'.)

Comment: Ah, got it: membership.permissions.projectAdmin would be the new way to access it with the string enums